# Material UI theme not being picked up by third party component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, draftjs

I have been working on this Material UI Rich Text Editor over here

https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-rte

I'm trying to follow best practices for both React and Material-UI so that anyone can pick it up and drop it in their project and it just works with Material

I'm having an issue where after running my build script and trying to actually import the editor into a project, I'm not getting any theme passed into the components in the editor, so palette colors or font families are not being represented in the editor at all which I thought they would be

When actually cloning the repo and running the `start` script, playing with the demo works with the theme when pulling the `Editor` from the src component but pulling it in from the `lib` directory like a normal use case would does not work with the theme.

Here is a codesandbox to illustrate this, I've set the theme to have a text color of lime green and the editor is not rendering this color at all. But if you clone and run the actual repo, the editor does use the lime color

https://codesandbox.io/embed/create-react-app-dw7gh

I would love some direction on this. Am I doing something wrong or missing something that material expects? Did I set up my build script wrong?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The theme propagation relies on a singleton to work. I would encourage the usage of @material-ui/styles as a peer dependency. Right now, it seems that you publish it: https://unpkg.com/material-ui-rte@1.1.3/lib/index.js. You should change that.

Comment: `@material-ui/styles` is marked as a peer dependency in the `package.json`. I'm not exactly following the line of logic here. I've wrapped the default export in a `StyleProidver` from `@material-ui/styles`, is there something about this setup I need to change to make it a `singleton` as you mention?

Comment: Facing the same issue here, any solution?